# Cannot add a key to Azure Key Vault in PowerShell - 'Unauthorized'

Tags: azure, powershell, authorization, azure-powershell, azure-keyvault

Okay so I am following the tutorial here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-get-started.  I am fine till the section **Add a key or secret to the key vault**

Basically it asks you to do this to a valid key vault:

```
$key = Add-AzureKeyVaultKey -VaultName 'DjangoKeyVault' -Name 'DjangoKey' -Destination 'Software'
```

It returns

```
Add-AzureKeyVaultKey : Operation returned an invalid status code 'Unauthorized'
```

I have tried this using Power Shell Command locally and logging into my Azure Account remotely.  I can verify the subscription and that the vault exists.  I can also use the 'PowerShellPreview' in Azure directly and get the same deal.  How in the world can I be the admin of the Azure site, logged in with elevated permissions, and not have authorization?  Do I need to set up Azure AD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I test the command, it works fine on my side.

[image]

Also, I could reproduced your issue with a wrong `VaultName`, so I think you could check it first.

[image]

Besides, here is some information for you to refer. I use my account to run the command in the PowerShell ISE, my account is an `owner` of the subscription, the keyvault was created by my account.

> How in the world can I be the admin of the Azure site, logged in with elevated permissions, and not have authorization? Do I need to set up Azure AD?

You could try to do the steps below.

1.Add your account in the `Access control (IAM)` in the key vault.

2.Add your account in `Access policies` -> `Add new`

Comment: Thanks I will try that later.  Can you please let me know the commands to do 1 and 2?  Are they more powershell commands or do I add them through the Azure site UI?

Comment: @djangojazz You need to try the two steps in the azure portal.

Comment: Thanks, the ticket was 'Access policies'.  I was by default the 'owner' permission and had all access.  However I had no access policies.  That is strange I could create a key vault and then have no access policies.